# fill water with / by bucket

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

> I will fill water **with / by** bucket.

Kindly help me with this question

Comment: Please provide more context to the sentence. It is difficult to understand what you want to say. Also, I do not understand which is the problem where you need help.

Comment: Do you want to put water in a bucket or do you want to use a bucket to put water in something else?

Answer (score 1):

You can say:

> I will fill **something** with water using a bucket.

Here it might be possible to say:

> I will fill the water by bucket
>   I will fill the water with *a* bucket
>   I will fill it by bucket

This only works if your reader already knows what you are trying to fill with water. The last example shows that (in English) you are not filling water. You are using water *to fill*. You might fill **a tank**, but in that case:

> I will fill the tank by bucket

The alternative interpretation is that you want to just fill the bucket, in which case:

> I will fill the bucket with water.